# Why is my code not changing the class of the td on hover?

Tags: jquery

I'm unsure of what is going wrong in my code. I'm attempting to change classes when someone hovers over a td.

http://jsfiddle.net/leggosteveo/fxva0chn/

```
main = function () {
$('#navRow').children().hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hovLink');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hovLink');
});
};$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: [Look at the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) before asking a question on SO !

Comment: I suggest you to use css styles for this purpose: td:hover{....}

Comment: You've extra closing td in your jsfiddle, so it might also be there in your actual code, which is creating the problem....

Comment: @dystroy I've been making websites for about a month, I'm not as knowledgeable as you may be, but thank you for your input.

Comment: @Ragnar , I'm learning javascript and jquery, which is why I used jquery. But thank you for your insight. I will certainly put it to use.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal the extra closing td is what was actually causing the issue. So thank you again especially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css styles instead of jQuery, for example:

```
#navRow td {background:#fff;} /*default style*/
#navRow td:hover {background:#cdcdcd;} /*hover style*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate the insight rather than criticism. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`.children` is a method, not a property:

```
$('#navRow').children().hover(function () {
```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated it to a method, and it still seems to not be working. I'm looking to use the td elements as navigation buttons. This is the first full website I'm building.

Comment: @Stephen -- It's working...if you check the console, the class is being added.